# BASH arithmetic script

Tags: bash

My input file structure is the following:

```
input.txt   
 system.switch_cpus.commit.op_class_0::SimdFloatMultAcc            0      0.00%     59.63% # Class of committed instruction
    936 system.switch_cpus.commit.op_class_0::SimdFloatSqrt            0      0.00%     59.63% # Class of committed instruction
    937 system.switch_cpus.commit.op_class_0::MemRead      3451622     34.52%     94.15% # Class of committed instruction
    938 system.switch_cpus.commit.op_class_0::MemWrite       585428      5.85%    100.00% # Class of committed instruction
    939 system.switch_cpus.commit.op_class_0::FloatMemRead            0      0.00%    100.00% # Class of committed instruction
    940 system.switch_cpus.commit.op_class_0::FloatMemWrite            0      0.00%    100.00% # Class of committed instruction
    941 system.switch_cpus.commit.op_class_0::IprAccess            0      0.00%    100.00% # Class of committed instruction
    942 system.switch_cpus.commit.op_class_0::InstPrefetch            0      0.00%    100.00% # Class of committed instruction
    943 system.switch_cpus.commit.op_class_0::total     10000000                       # Class of committed instruction
    944 system.switch_cpus.commit.bw_lim_events      10000000                       # number cycles where commit BW limit reached
    945 system.switch_cpus.rob.rob_reads             80558432                       # The number of ROB reads
    946 system.switch_cpus.rob.rob_writes            43430539                       # The number of ROB writes
    947 system.switch_cpus.timesIdled                   37218                       # Number of times that the entire CPU went into an idle     state and unscheduled itself
    948 system.switch_cpus.idleCycles                 2755508                       # Total number of cycles that the CPU has spent unsched    uled due to idling
    949 system.switch_cpus.committedInsts            10000000                       # Number of Instructions Simulated
    950 system.switch_cpus.committedOps              10000000                       # Number of Ops (including micro ops) Simulated
    951 system.switch_cpus.cpi                       8.369191                       # CPI: Cycles Per Instruction
    952 system.switch_cpus.cpi_total                 8.369191                       # CPI: Total CPI of All Threads
    953 system.switch_cpus.ipc                       0.119486                       # IPC: Instructions Per Cycle
    954 system.switch_cpus.ipc_total                 0.119486                       # IPC: Total IPC of All Threads
    955 system.switch_cpus.int_regfile_reads         21773538                       # number of integer regfile reads
    956 system.switch_cpus.int_regfile_writes         9447282                       # number of integer regfile writes
```

I am trying to find a value which is not directly reported in the input file, but needs a simple arithmetic operation.

Here is the code I am using:

```
Code:
  1 list=(IPC CycleCount CommitCount LDQ_Stall STQ_Stall IQ_Stall ROB_STALL BTBMiss BrCount BrMisPred LDCount STCount ICacheMissCount L    d_miss_Count St_miss_Count)
  2 IPC="system.switch_cpus.ipc"
  3 CycleCount="system.switch_cpus.numCycles"
  4 CommitCount="system.switch_cpus.commit.committedInsts"
  5 LDQ_Stall="system.switch_cpus.rename.LQFullEvents"
  6 STQ_Stall="system.switch_cpus.rename.SQFullEvents"
  7 IQ_Stall="system.switch_cpus.rename.IQFullEvents"
  8 ROB_STALL="system.switch_cpus.rename.ROBFullEvents"
  9 BTBLookups="system.switch_cpus.branchPred.BTBLookups"
 10 BTBHits="system.switch_cpus.branchPred.BTBHits"
 11 #BTBMiss="$BTBLookups-$BTBHits"
 12 BrCount="system.switch_cpus.commit.branches"
 13 BrMisPred="system.switch_cpus.commit.branchMispredicts"
 14 LDCount="system.switch_cpus.commit.loads"
 15 #STCount="system.switch_cpus.commit.refs"-"$LDCount"
 16 IcacheMissCount="system.cpu.icache.overall_misses::total"
 17 Ld_miss_Count="system.cpu.dcache.ReadReq_misses::total"
 18 St_miss_Count="system.cpu.dcache.WriteReq_misses::total"
 19 
 20 
 21 
 22 
 23 
 24 for i in ${list[@]}:
 25   do 
 26   #  echo "$i"
 27     echo ${!i}
 28     if [ "${i}" == "BTBMiss"]; then
 29       lookup=$(awk -v a="${BTBLookups}" '{if ($1==a) {print $2})
 30       hits=$(awk -v a="${BTBHits}" '{if ($1==a) {print $2}}) 
 31       echo "$i = $((lookup-hits))"
 32  
 33     elif [$i=="STCount"];then
 34                                                                                                                                    
 35       refcount=`awk '($1=="system.switch_cpus.commit.refs") {print $2}'`
 36       ldcount=`awk '($1=="system.switch_cpus.commit.loads") {print$2}'`
 37       echo "$i = $((refcount-ldcount))"
 38       
 39     else
 40     awk -v a="${!i}" '{if ($1==a) {print $2}}' $1
 41   fi
 42   done
```

For each list element, if the element matches "BTBMiss", it should find the values listed in the code and report the number. Otherwise, it would do the regular operation of finding each element value from the input.txt file. 
Running the code, I am getting some weird problem with the "if" statements in my code:

```
$--> ./parser.sh  input.txt 
system.switch_cpus.ipc
./parser.sh: line 28: [: missing `]'
./parser.sh: line 33: [IPC==STCount]: command not found
0.119486
system.switch_cpus.numCycles
./parser.sh: line 28: [: missing `]'
./parser.sh: line 33: [CycleCount==STCount]: command not found
83691906
system.switch_cpus.commit.committedInsts
./parser.sh: line 28: [: missing `]'
./parser.sh: line 33: [CommitCount==STCount]: command not found
10000000
system.switch_cpus.rename.LQFullEvents
./parser.sh: line 28: [: missing `]'
./parser.sh: line 33: [LDQ_Stall==STCount]: command not found
59696
system.switch_cpus.rename.SQFullEvents
./parser.sh: line 28: [: missing `]'
./parser.sh: line 33: [STQ_Stall==STCount]: command not found
1546
system.switch_cpus.rename.IQFullEvents
./parser.sh: line 28: [: missing `]'
./parser.sh: line 33: [IQ_Stall==STCount]: command not found
109463
system.switch_cpus.rename.ROBFullEvents
./parser.sh: line 28: [: missing `]'
./parser.sh: line 33: [ROB_STALL==STCount]: command not found
9574

./parser.sh: line 28: [: missing `]'
./parser.sh: line 33: [BTBMiss==STCount]: command not found


system.switch_cpus.commit.branches
./parser.sh: line 28: [: missing `]'
./parser.sh: line 33: [BrCount==STCount]: command not found
2478601
system.switch_cpus.commit.branchMispredicts
./parser.sh: line 28: [: missing `]'
./parser.sh: line 33: [BrMisPred==STCount]: command not found
442168
system.switch_cpus.commit.loads
./parser.sh: line 28: [: missing `]'
./parser.sh: line 33: [LDCount==STCount]: command not found
3451622

./parser.sh: line 28: [: missing `]'
./parser.sh: line 33: [STCount==STCount]: command not found



./parser.sh: line 28: [: missing `]'
./parser.sh: line 33: [ICacheMissCount==STCount]: command not found


system.cpu.dcache.ReadReq_misses::total
./parser.sh: line 28: [: missing `]'
./parser.sh: line 33: [Ld_miss_Count==STCount]: command not found
2233581

./parser.sh: line 28: [: missing `]'
./parser.sh: line 33: [St_miss_Count:==STCount]: command not found
```

what am i doing wrong with the if...elif...else statements?

Comment: spaces are necessary if you use `[`. please read a bash tutorial before writing bash code as it sometimes can be very counterintuitive, e.g. http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: added space in the if statements. Error gone. But now there is no result printed out. It is stuck at the first element.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working:

```
 1 list=(IPC CycleCount CommitCount LDQ_Stall STQ_Stall IQ_Stall ROB_STALL BTBMiss BrCount BrMisPred LDCount STCount IcacheMissCount Ld_miss_Count St_miss_Count)
  2 IPC="system.switch_cpus.ipc"
  3 CycleCount="system.switch_cpus.numCycles"
  4 CommitCount="system.switch_cpus.commit.committedInsts"
  5 LDQ_Stall="system.switch_cpus.rename.LQFullEvents"
  6 STQ_Stall="system.switch_cpus.rename.SQFullEvents"
  7 IQ_Stall="system.switch_cpus.rename.IQFullEvents"
  8 ROB_STALL="system.switch_cpus.rename.ROBFullEvents"
  9 BTBLookups="system.switch_cpus.branchPred.BTBLookups"
 10 BTBHits="system.switch_cpus.branchPred.BTBHits"
 11 #BTBMiss="$BTBLookups-$BTBHits"
 12 BrCount="system.switch_cpus.commit.branches"
 13 BrMisPred="system.switch_cpus.commit.branchMispredicts"
 14 LDCount="system.switch_cpus.commit.loads"
 15 #STCount="system.switch_cpus.commit.refs"-"$LDCount"
 16 IcacheMissCount="system.cpu.icache.overall_misses::total"
 17 Ld_miss_Count="system.cpu.dcache.ReadReq_misses::total"
 18 St_miss_Count="system.cpu.dcache.WriteReq_misses::total"
 19 
 20 
 21 
 22 
 23 
 24 for i in "${list[@]}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 25   do
 26   #  echo "$i"
 27    # echo ${!i}
 28     if [ "${i}" == "BTBMiss" ]; then
 29       lookup=$(awk -v a="${BTBLookups}" '{if ($1==a) print $2}' $1)
 30       hits=$(awk -v a="${BTBHits}" '{if ($1==a) print $2}' $1)
 31       echo "$i = $((lookup-hits))"
 32 
 33     elif [ $i == "STCount" ];then
 34 
 35       refcount=`awk '($1=="system.switch_cpus.commit.refs") {print $2}' $1`
 36       ldcount=`awk '($1=="system.switch_cpus.commit.loads") {print$2}' $1`
 37       echo "$i = $((refcount-ldcount))"
 38 
 39     else
 40     value=$(awk -v a="${!i}" '{if ($1==a) print $2}' $1)
 41     echo "$i = $value"
 42   fi
 43   done
```

Output:

```
./parser.sh  out/stats.txt 
IPC = 0.119486
CycleCount = 83691906
CommitCount = 10000000
LDQ_Stall = 59696
STQ_Stall = 1546
IQ_Stall = 109463
ROB_STALL = 9574
BTBMiss = 3562
BrCount = 2478601
BrMisPred = 442168
LDCount = 3451622
STCount = 585428
IcacheMissCount = 36218
Ld_miss_Count = 2233581
St_miss_Count = 207436
```